# Actionmailer Emails seem to be sent in the console and logs but they never arrive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, email, linode

Rails 3.0.0

Here is my configuration in environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
    :port                 => 587,  
    :domain               => "<domain>",  
    :user_name            => "<un>@gmail.com",  
    :password             => "<pw>",  
    :authentication       => "plain",  
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  
  }

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I've also tried commenting out the domain as suggested in a different Stack Overflow post.

I've tried sending the mail both through my app and in the console.  In the console there are no errors and it returns the mail object but displays nothing else.  When I try sending though the app the log says that it rendered my user mailer template.

I'm hosting my app on Linode but they assure me this method "should" work and that Linode shouldn't be the problem.  I've also checked to make sure my app was running in "production."

Any ideas for debugging this?  I've tried sending to three different common email hosts.

EDIT: Here is my code for sending a mail in the console:

```
user_mailer.rb

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "myaccount@gmail.com"
  layout 'user_layout' 

  def activation(user)
    @user = user    
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => 'Activate your account')  
  end

end

console command

> u = User.last
> u.email
#myotheraccount@gmail.com
> UserMailer.activation(u).deliver
```

UPDATE 2: When I add a text only view template, that sends fine.  So something is only wrong with sending the HTML versions.  I've simplified all of my HTML templates to contain simple tags and the standard doctype html but still no dice.

Comment: What exact code are you using to send the mailer?

Comment: Added email sending code

Comment: It's been a few months--did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yeah, it turned out to be the codebase I inherited was using something called "Delayed Job" to queue HTML emails and send them in batches but the batch sender was turned off.  All the code I posted in my question was fine.